# React & Express server not getting api requests in production /build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, production

I have a React app running successfully locally and all api requests are successfully running from a separate server.
When I run a build, the path to the api server is lost and no data is loaded.
Below are a few screenshots...

Loading data successfully from api.
[image]

Pointing IIS to react /build folder using localhost:80. No data loading.
[image]

Here is an example of an api call in my node/express server/index.js file

```
app.get('/api/company', (req, res) => {
api_helper.GET('https://****/api/company')
    .then(response => {
        res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
```

})

My package.json file has the url of the express proxy (running in the background).

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

My question is, why isnt the api loading in production /build? I just get this...

Request URL: http://localhost/api/site
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

but when just running locally (npm start) I get this and data loads from api.

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/site
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Any help appreciated, driving me mad! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After much testing I discovered, you must put the routes before

Wrong Example:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/', routes);
```

Right Example:

```
app.use('/api', routes);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I figured it out..

I had to add this to my express server.js file in the root folder of my project.

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

I then pointed to the address where express is running, in my case http://localhost:5000

This worked.

I also then set up a rewrite rule in IIS to point localhost and our domain name to localhost:5000

All working now, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: hi there can you elaborate a bit more on the rewrite rule in IIS? I have a proxy port for my api requests, should that port be what i rewrite the rule to?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your info. I am quite new to ReactJS and I also encountered similar problems when I created my production build. Actually I had added similar things like

```
app.use(express.static(<build_folder_dir>));
```

in my Express Server before then I came to search and see your post. Anyway, I did not add something like the second line of your code and my API calls are written in router created in a separate js file.

```
app.use('/api/some_path', <imported_router>);
```

In the exported router object, codes are written like this:

```
router.get('/some_sub-path')
```

To make API calls, I used axios in my react app

```
axios.get(
      "/api/some_path"+"/sub-path?param_1="+<param_value>,
      {
        headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json",
          <some headers>
        }
      }
).then((res)=>{<Some codes using the res.data.<any param in body>>})
```

---

Finally,I added these lines in the server.js

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, <path of the index.html in the build dir>), function(err) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send(err)
            }
          })

  })
```

Yet, I made a stupid mistake that my app crashed because the app.get overwrite the settings in router. Just a reminder, if you enable any API calls in GET method, use regex to exclude the pattern for making API calls.